# Show that $(p^{n+1} - 1)/(p -1)$ is even if and only if $n+1$ is even

Tags: number-theory

> Show that if $p \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ is odd and $\geq 3$, and $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, then $(p^{n+1} - 1)/(p -1)$ is even if and only if $n+1$ is even, and $(p^{n+1} - 1)/(p-1) \equiv 0 \mod 4$ if and only if either $n \equiv -1 \mod 4$ or $p \equiv -1 \mod 4$ and $n \equiv 1 \mod 2$.
>
> *HINT*: Divide $p^{n+1} - 1$ by $p -1$, and divide $p^{2k} - 1$ by $p^2 - 1$ if $n+1 = 2k$ is even.

In the answers, it starts of by saying

"We have

$$\frac{p^n + 1}{p - 1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} p^k,$$

which is the sum of $n$ odd numbers - which is even if and only if $n$ is even."

Where does this come from? How do we know this?

Comment: Note that your question talks about $p^{n+1} -1 1$, while your solution is looking at $p^n +1$. You should resolve that difference of $\pm$, and also the different index. The different index would explain why there's the confusion about even / odd.

Answer (score 1):

In general, we have
$$ 1 + a + a^2 + \cdots + a^n = \dfrac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$$
as sum of terms of a [geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression).
Hence, we have
$$\dfrac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1} = 1 + p + p^2 + \cdots + p^n$$where each term is odd and there are $n+1$ odd terms. So...

Comment: Why does the summation go to $n-1$ as opposed to $n$ then?

Comment: @Kaish How many integers are there between $0$ and $n$ (inclusive)?

Comment: Also, wouldn't that make that sum odd? For example $3 + 5 + 7$ is three odd integers, which is odd. I thought if you had an odd amount of odd integers, then your answer is odd.

Comment: @Calvin Lin $n + 1$. Oh, ok, I get that bit.

Comment: @Kaish (sorry I was referencing user's solution, not the one that you shown above). Note that your question is different from the question that the solution is answering. Your question uses $p^{n+1}$, while the solution uses $p^n$ instead.

Comment: @Kaish If $n+1$ is even, then you are adding even number of odd numbers, so...